# Meaning of clearance of generation analysis memory growth on simulator "simulate memory warning" event

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, xcode-instruments

I was trying to debug the memory growth in generation analysis and was frustrated (Lots of objects that was the result of call toCGGlyphBitmapCreate was not being released) . Then, I ran the program on simulator and captured many generation snapshots and then I did a simulate memory warning. Almost every generation cleared to zero ( a few had a few bytes here and there). Does that mean my code is fine and I should not worry about it? How can I prevent the growth so that it wont have to wait until a simulate memory warning event to clear the growth? (By the way, all these growth was caused by system libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory is getting released upon memory warning, then you're probably OK. The OS will cache all sorts of stuff (that it will free/reuse as it sees fit) that you don't generally have to be concerned about.

Still, I would run the code through the static analyzer (press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Xcode or select "Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu) just to be safe.